# How to run exe from c# dll which is called from asp

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, dotnethighcharts

I have create c# dll which is contained in web directory of the product. This dll contain a function which accept some parameters and call a exe (phantomjs.exe) with accepted parameters.I also have write some logging code for file writing in this function. 
 Now I call this dll from asp classic code. Then I found that log maintain by this dll but work of phantomjs.exe does not occur. While when I call this dll from console application then phantomjs.exe works.

I use below code to call the exe

```
Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = pDirectory + "\\res\\bin\\phantomjs.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Please tell me will there be a need to sign this phantomjs.exe to run in webdirectory or any thing else.

Comment: the given code is the one in your console application... we can't help you if you do not include relevant code (in this case asp-classic)

Comment: but now asp code is able to call dll which is verify by watching that log maintain on a file in dll occurs. But execution of phantomjs.exe does not occur and also no exception thrown. That's why I am asking will exe need any type of signing or any thing else

Comment: in general not. you just have to compile as a valid exe. dll's cannot be executed as standalone. they must be executed by something like rundll32.exe and always need a function to execute. for reference check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Features_of_DLL)

Comment: I am running dll with vbscript, and I have register the dll.